# Loading font-family from disk to PrivateFontCollection

Tags: c#, gdi+, privatefontcollection

I'm using the following code to load a font into memory for generating an image with GDI+:

```
var fontCollection = new PrivateFontCollection();
fontCollection.AddFontFile(Server.MapPath("~/fonts/abraham-webfont.ttf"));
fontCollection.Families.Count(); // => This line tells me, that the collection has 0 items.
```

There are no exceptions, but the fontCollection Families property is empty after the `AddFontFile` method has run without any exceptions.

I've verified that the path is valid (`File.Exists` returns `true`):

```
Response.Write(System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/fonts/abraham-webfont.ttf"))); // # => Renders "True"
```

The TTF-file seems to work fine, when I open the file, so it's not an invalid TTF-file:
[image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4899329/2016-10-12_22-44-52.png]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you doing it on localhost or stage/production env with additional paths?

Comment: PrivateFontCollection is notoriously flakey.  One failure mode that's pretty common today is that the font is actually an OpenType font with TrueType outlines.  GDI+ only supports "pure" ones.  The shoe fits, the web says that Abraham is an OpenType font.  Works in WPF, not in Winforms.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks! Please submit this comment as an answer so I can accept it. The problem was the font - not the code.

Comment: Surely you can complete your Q+A yourself now?  You don't need my help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from Hans Passant solved the problem:

*PrivateFontCollection is notoriously flakey. One failure mode that's pretty common today is that the font is actually an OpenType font with TrueType outlines. GDI+ only supports "pure" ones. The shoe fits, the web says that Abraham is an OpenType font. Works in WPF, not in Winforms.*